# How to get a special stylesheet from document.styleSheets

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a lot of stylesheets in my page. Now i want to load one of them into a variable.

```
var sheets = document.styleSheets;
```

now i can make a for loop and a if match... rule to loop throug all sheets and return the one i want.

In the console i see that the stylesheetlist is build like this

```
...
16: StyleSheet https://www.example.com/mystyles.css
...
```

So my question is, is it possible to get directly the Stylesheet "16: StyleSheet https://www.example.com/mystyles.css" from the list or is there no other way as loop through all the sheets?

Thanks a lot for explainig me that.

Comment: The order isn't 100% guaranteed, so to write some robust code you'll need to loop through the StyleSheetList returned from `document.styleSheets` to find the exact one you're after by its `href`. You can use `filter()` to make this easier. I'd ask why you feel the need to do this, though, as it's a rather odd requirement which almost seems like a code smell.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Rory McCrossan How could a filter functions looks like, can i filter for the url?

Comment: `var sheet = sheets.filter(sheet => sheet.href == 'https://example.com/foo.css');` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: You could use `document.querySelector('link[rel=stylesheet][href="https://www.example.com/mystyles.css"]').sheet)` but this is not any better IMHO :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thats looks like what i want to make my code a little bit smaler, but if i try i get "....filter is not a function"

Comment: Try `Array.from(sheets).filter(...`

Comment: that it is - thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is it possible to combine it with .match("/myfile.css$")
for the case i only know the exact end of the css file?

Comment: Yes, you can put whatever condition you like in the filter arrow function

Comment: Ok, but this wont work!?
" var mysheet = Array.from(sheets).filter(mysheet => mysheet.href.match("/css/myfile.css$"));" - i get a .href is null - without the match part, it works fine!?